# How can binaural beats change mental state?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, hearing, cognition

Can anyone tell me how binaural beats of 10 Hz can cause a person to calm down and one of 40 Hz to cause someone to heighten their attention. All I know is that they work on the principal of Brainwave Entrainment. I am confused as to how can a 10-Hz difference in 2 sounds cause the brain to change its state of mind! A detailed but simple explanation would be great.

[image: Binaural Beats]

[image: Second image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is thought that binaural beats entrain the brain in the frequency of the binaural beat. These beat frequencies show up in the **[EEG](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/eeg/basics/definition/prc-20014093)**.

The EEG in turn represents synchronous activity in the cerebral cortex (Fig. 1).

[image: EEG]
<sup>Fig. 1. EEG frequency bands and their associate mental states. source: [Conor Russomanno](https://conorrussomanno.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/2.png)</sup>

Now if you look at where 10 Hz EEG waves show up it is in the alpha frequency band associated with a relaxed mental state. The 40 Hz band on the other hand is associated with beta activity associated with an alert state.

Indeed, presentation of beta-frequency binaural beats have shown to improve the performance on psychophysical tasks and performances were better than when binaural beats were presented in the theta-delta range [(Lane *et al*., 1998)](https://www.i-doser.com/binauralsandmood.pdf).

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Lane *et al*., *Physiol Behav* (1998); **63**(2): 249–52](https://www.i-doser.com/binauralsandmood.pdf)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I will put here a link that I think explained this phenomenon more fully by looking at a huge number of different scientific studies done on the matter...
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4428073/#!po=11.3861

If you find the article too long, read the last paragraphs to find their conclusions.

Comment: Please summarize the major points of the link here. It's also good to provide a citation in your answer. Both ensure that your answer remains useful in the future if your link dies. Thanks